# Regex to match pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string in the following format

```
ABC=23:Qasd=56:Def=40.44
```

I would like to replace all the strings (`ABC=`, `Qasd=` and `Def=`)  with empty string. The string after `=` can be anything. So my output string would be

```
23:56:40.44
```

It would be great if you can let me know the regex for that in C#

Comment: Have you had a look at [Regex Library](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx)? Their regex tester might be more helpful than posting incomplete questions here and waiting for a reply.

Comment: To supplement Sebastian Weber: http://regexhero.net/tester/ and http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(^|:)[^=]*=
```

replaced with

```
$1
```

Matches the beginning of a string or a `:` and everything until and including `=`.
It is replaced with `$1` to keep `:`.

C#

```
string strTargetString = @"ABC=23:Qasd=56:Def=40.44";

var myRegex = new Regex(@"(^|:)[^=]*=");    
var result = myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, @"$1");

//result: 23:56:40.44
```

More examples:

```
ABC=hello:Qasd=56:Def=40.44 => hello:56:40.44
```

Comment: The string after = can be anything. Can you modify the regex accordingly and let me know.

Comment: @Derin add more examples of what you need to match to your question then.

Answer (score 2):

Match

```
^[^=]+=|(?<=:)[^=]+=
```

and replace with string.Empty

```
Regex.Replace("ABC=23:Qasd=56:Def=40.44", @"^[^=]+=|(?<=:)[^=]+=", string.Empty);
```

Comment: lasseespeholt's should work... though I like the smiley in my answer

Comment: Works for me when run in linqpad. NOt sure if later edits might have fixed that though...

Comment: +1 I don't know why you changed your solution, your first version worked fine for me. This solution is also fine, but can be simplified to `(?<=^|:)[^=]+=`